# How to use Sakai LMS(Learning Management System) unstructured data?

Tags: data-analysis, sakai, lms

Is there any way to analyze unstructured data of Sakai LMS? Does anyone have any experience of Sakai unstructured data analytics? Please share your experience and thoughts. I am trying to learn.

Thank you.

Comment: Which 'unstructured data' do you mean?

Comment: Usually, the backend database for Sakai is MySql. I was interested in if there is any other user activity or Log data which are unstructured.

Comment: I'm not sure about the latest versions, but Sakai logs access info to a database table; of course you can also use the webserver logs. Personally I used querying on the database.using [this homegrown script](https://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/sakai-bin/sakai-sessions) (called `sakai-sessions` because initially it was only used to list sessions). BTW I advise against growing scripts to be this large - I should have refactored it.